# Difference between Data abstraction and procedural abstraction in java

Tags: java, abstraction

I am trying to understand the difference between Data abstraction and procedural abstraction in java.

I understand the procedural abstraction is making use of methods that accept formal parameters and hiding the implementation from the user. This totally makes sense in `PL/SQL` language as I have an option of creating procedures separately in `PL/SQL`.

But I get confused between Data abstraction and Procedural abstraction, as even the procedures in Java are implemented as part of some class. And every class can also have some static methods(`public static`) which every other class in the package can use.

Please can someone give a clear distinction between these two(in terms of java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Procedural Abstraction, methods are used to capture the procedural patterns, abstracting over behaviour.
For example, in Java, you could write something like:

```
public void printFibonacci(int n){
//your code to print Fibonacci numbers
}
```

In this way, users could use the procedure easily, without even having to wonder what's going on inside the function. You know that it will print the fibonacci for the given input.

On the other hand, in Data Abstraction, Classes are used to abstract the related stateful values and their associated behaviours -- also called a s Abstract Data Type (ADT).
For example, in Java, it consists of:

1. Interface classes
2. The allowable behaviours

Answer (score 1):

In Object Oriented Programming, abstraction is one of the major pillars. In Java, when it comes to data abstraction, it means while designing/defining the classes itself, you need to identify only those attributes of class which are relevant to that domain. For example, if Person is an entity, it can have many attributes such as first name, surname, salary, spouse, age, height, weight, blood group. But if you are developing an application for healthcare domain, then you want to choose only those attributes which are related to healthcare (e.g. height, blood group) and ignore the rest. On the other hand, if you are developing an application for social survey, these attributes are not required. In this way, identifying the required attributes and ignoring the rest is the data abstraction.

As for the procedural abstraction, the necessary part is "What the procedure does and ignoring how it does it". Most of the languages by default support it. In Java, one class can call methods of other class without knowing its implementation details. This is one example of procedural abstraction.